# How many times a number appears as a leaf node?

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

Suppose you have an array of n elements 
A = {1,2,3,4,5}
total of 5! binary search trees are possible(not necessarily distinct) now my question is in how many of trees 1 appeared as leaf node and in how many 2 appeared as leaf node and so on ?

What I have tried:

I've seen for A = {1,2,3}

2 appears 6/3 = 2 times

1 appears 2+1 = 3 times

3 appears 2+1 = 3 times

can i generalise that and say that, 
if A= {1,2,3,4}

2 = 24/4 = 6 times

3 = 24/4 = 6 times

1 = 6+1 = 7 times

4 = 6+1 = 7 times

Comment: In your first example,plz explain how does 1 appear 3 times...

Comment: There are 6 possible trees draw them and you will get the answer !! and yes consider all 6 trees even tho we know one 5 distinct trees are possible and one would be repetition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can generalize, but not in that way.

You can try to permute the array and produce all possible BST's. A brute-force approach, that returns answer in a map/dictionary data structure shouldn't be that hard. First write a function that given one of permuted arrays, finds all leaves. It takes first element as root, sends all elements less than root to left, all greater ones to right, and calls this function recursively for both of them. It then just returns after combining those values.

In the end, combine values for all possible permutations.

A possible approach in python:

```
from itertools import permutations

def func(arr):
    if not arr: return {}
    if len(arr)==1: return {arr[0]}

    ans = set()
    left = func([v for v in arr[1:] if v<arr[0]])
    right = func([v for v in arr[1:] if v>=arr[0]])
    ans.update(left)
    ans.update(right)
    return ans

arr = [1,2,3,4]
ans = {i:0 for i in arr}
for a in permutations(arr):
    dic = func(a)
    print(a,":",dic)
    for k in dic:
        ans[k]+=1

print(ans)
```

for `[1,2,3]` it outputs:

```
(1, 2, 3) : {3}
(1, 3, 2) : {2}
(2, 1, 3) : {1, 3}
(2, 3, 1) : {1, 3}
(3, 1, 2) : {2}
(3, 2, 1) : {1}
{1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 3}
```

for `[1,2,3,4]`, only the last line i.e answer is:

```
{1: 12, 2: 8, 3: 8, 4: 12}
```

for `[1,2,3,4,5]`, it is :

```
{1: 60, 2: 40, 3: 40, 4: 40, 5: 60}
```

Can you see the pattern? well, one last example. For up to `6` it is:

```
{1: 360, 2: 240, 3: 240, 4: 240, 5: 240, 6: 360}
```

Comment: Yes, I got the pattern it was difficult to find it without making a program. Thanks !!